# How to download a secured wsdl using url using certificate?

Tags: web-services, security, wsdl

Generally to download a wsdl file I would do it by displaying the wsdl in the browser.

e.g.: to download the wsdl endpoint - http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx

step 1: append the endpoint with '?wsdl' and paste the url in a browser
http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl

step 2: save as the wsdl file shown in the local file system.

But in this case I have a secured web service, and they have provided me with the endpoint, certificates and the private keys.

If i just do the steps above I am egtting the error below

> 502 Bad Gateway
>
> This server received an invalid response from a server it consulted
>   when acting as a proxy or gateway.

How do I download the wsdl. Please help.